When did PC hard drives no longer require you to park the heads?
It wasn't MFM or RLL. IDE? SATA?
Yes, I know these are encoding methods. But their introduction corresponds to times, and it's those times and those drives that I remember fondly, When life was simpler and understandable, and interleave was always greater than 1.

The last thing you'd want to do inside a hard drive is stick in a big electromagnet.

Related question for those unfamiliar with "parking the heads".

Are you only interested in PC hard drives, or hard drives in general? Also, the question implies that parking is required, but if it was required, then a head would crash to platter simply during a power outage, and a lot of hard drives would be damaged. So can you be more specific about what do you mean by parking no longer required, if hard drives did survive even without parking? In PCs, usually you would park the head if you knew you were going to e.g. move the equipment so it can tolerate shocks better.

Well just never mind then.

@Justme Yep, I have a memory that (auto)park became a big topic when laptops (or whatever passed as (trans)portable initially) with hard disks became a thing (which latter triggered the introduction of g-sensors to park on free-fall detection). Before that it was a matter of "parking before moving the drive/computer".

@jcaron That reminds me, I'm still salty that Dell pre-installed and has running the software to monitor for free-fall conditions and park the drive even when there are no spinning drives in the system!

MFM and RLL are recording methods while IDE and SATA are host interfaces. Neither of them are an indicator for generation or related to parking abilities.
In general, drives on their own do not "autopark", but device controllers, host controller or OS may do so. It's a software feature delivered by either component.
Mainframes did park the head assembly since early on as part of their I/O routines. Likewise SCSI device controllers (*1), as they provide their own CPU to handle that - together with the build in knowledge where to land best.
PCs using SCSI disk systems most likely had "autopark" right from the start. But IBM did not include the luxury of an 'intelligent' controllers with their XT, nor does BIOS handle parking. In fact, DOS as well doesn't care. That's why somewhat simple programs like PARK.COM showed up to handle this. While not putting the heads in a designated landing zone, they made at least sure that possible damage was redirected to less critical areas than boot sector, root-directory or DOS-image.
To solve this (missing) software issue in hardware, some drive manufacturers added an autopark feature, where in case of power cut off the energy stored in the disks was used to move the head to park.
When Compaq introduced IDE in 1985 to save cost, autopark became a standard feature, as now those drives also had their private intelligent controller.
Now, for the 'spring' you mention, those were some (connors?) drives which didn't really 'autopark' but lifted the head far off the surface, giving a floppy like sound :)) At least that's how I remember it.

*1 - That's the one controlling the device, like an OMI 5000, not the host controller providing the bus (like an Adaptec AH2940).

.
MFM and RLL are recording methods while IDE and SATA are host interfaces.  === Yeah, I know. But I'm using that as a proxy for... for what else? Other than year or  model numbers, it's all I really have to identify when this feature was first available === >in case of power cut off the energy stored in the disks was used to move the head to park. == oh my god, thst is SUCH an elegant solution! Winning answer.

@MissUnderstands Technicallly, from a line coding point of view, MFM is just one specific instance of RLL coding. Also used incorrectly to somehow classify hard drive generations.

I’m aware of a variety of implementations, some relying on the controller or OS (the latter especially on systems expecting some form of UPS), some relying on more “physical” systems implemented in the drive. There are as one might expect a ton of patents in this area; US4866554A is a good place to start, the patents citing it lead to many more related inventions. US5889629A is explicitly about retraction under control of the drive’s microcontroller.

@StephenKitt yes, people are quite creative if there's an issue to be solved. I only tried to give a rough frame beside narrow mainstream memory.. It's in no way exhaustive or detailed.

@MissUnderstands wasn't intended to criticise in any way, just to lay out the environment.

@Raffzahn of course — I was only providing pointers for curious readers.

Many non-PC systems had to 'park' their heads because ... packs were removable!   Of course, in this case parking was not on the disc surface at all.

@dave Yeah, but I was talking about emergency retraction at power fail.

Pretty much all PDP-11 removable-pack disk drives had emergency retraction, as far as I recall.  It seems like it would be negligent design to NOT do that.

When I took assembly language in college and learned that instructions existed for directly controlling the hard disk heads, I dove for the power switch like an Olympic diver the moment it became clear my program had started executing the contents of memory as instructions because while unlikely there was a non-zero chance my hard disk might get damaged. Those were the days! :D

Later MFM/RLL drives would auto-park (ST-252 for example). I was under the impression that all IDE drives auto-parked, but the thread linked above mentions that the WD93044-A required manual parking. The WD93044-A installation manual mentions that “At the end of each computer session you should park the drive heads.” and points to Western Digital’s PARKIDE utility.
In any case the vast majority of IDE drives auto-parked.
Many early drives used stepper motors to move heads; I don’t think overriding a spring with an electromagnet would work there.

The ST-252! And the ST-220! I remember! Lord, I remember...

I was able to verify the WD drive requiring manual parking: https://stason.org/TULARC/pc/hard-drives-hdd/western-digital/WD-93044-A-43MB-3-5-HH-IDE-AT.html

I think you're asking about PCs, but there were also some pre-PC drives which parked automatically.  The heads on those drives would park when power was lost, without any action needed by the drive, drive controller, or computer.  One such drive that I used was the CDC Hawk 5, which I used on the MODCOMP IV minicomputer.  The drive used a linear voice coil motor to position the head.  I'm not sure what the retraction mechanism was, but I am pretty sure it was mechanical in nature.  Possibly a permanent magnet.
Another contemporary computer which used the same Hawk drive was the Centurion.  You can see a Centurion's Hawk drive being restored on the Usagi Electric Youtube channel in this video.

From what I understand, a lot of voice coil mechanisms have a spring which will continuously try to push the head outward unless oppposed by the voice coil (which would naturally cease such opposition if it loses power).

The earliest disk drives which used light enough heads that landing them on the desk was safe were IBM's "Winchester" models. These originated in the mainframe world, but the Winchester technology was applied to PC disks almost as soon as PCs acquired hard drives. I have an IBM "luggable" machine, early 1980s, which has a 20 MB winchester drive.
Note that this has nothing to do with the interface generation; it predates having more than one option in PC drive interfaces.
